# How to convert from 8byte hex to real

Tags: swift, converters

I'm currently working on a file converter. I've never done anything using binary file reading before. There are many converters available for this file type (gdsII to text), but none in swift that I can find.

I've gotten all the other data types working (2byte int, 4byte int), but I'm really struggling with the real data type.

From a spec document :
http://www.cnf.cornell.edu/cnf_spie9.html

Real numbers are not represented in IEEE format. A floating point number is made up of three parts: the sign, the exponent, and the mantissa. The value of the number is defined to be (mantissa) (16) (exponent). If "S" is the sign bit, "E" is exponent bits, and "M" are mantissa bits then an 8-byte real number has the format

```
SEEEEEEE MMMMMMMM MMMMMMMM MMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMM MMMMMMMM MMMMMMMM MMMMMMMM
```

The exponent is in "excess 64" notation; that is, the 7-bit field shows a number that is 64 greater than the actual exponent. The mantissa is always a positive fraction greater than or equal to 1/16 and less than 1. For an 8-byte real, the mantissa is in bits 8 to 63. The decimal point of the binary mantissa is just to the left of bit 8. Bit 8 represents the value 1/2, bit 9 represents 1/4, and so on.

I've tried implementing something similar to what I've seen in python or Perl but each language has features that swift doesn't have, also the type conversions get very confusing.

This is one method I tried, based on Perl. Doesn't seem to get the right value. Bitwise math is new to me.

```
       var sgn = 1.0
        let andSgn = 0x8000000000000000 & bytes8_test
        if( andSgn > 0) { sgn = -1.0 }

       // var sgn = -1 if 0x8000000000000000 & num else 1
        let manta = bytes8_test & 0x00ffffffffffffff
        let exp = (bytes8_test >> 56) & 0x7f
        let powBase = sgn * Double(manta)
        let expPow = (4.0 * (Double(exp) - 64.0) - 56.0)
        var testReal = pow( powBase , expPow )
```

Another I tried:

```
let bitArrayDecode = decodeBitArray(bitArray: bitArray)
        let valueArray = calcValueOfArray(bitArray: bitArrayDecode)
        var exponent:Int16
        //calculate exponent
        if(negative){
            exponent = valueArray - 192
        } else {
            exponent = valueArray - 64
        }
        //calculate mantessa
        var mantissa = 0.0
        //sgn = -1 if 0x8000000000000000 & num else 1
        //mant = num & 0x00ffffffffffffff
        //exp = (num >> 56) & 0x7f
        //return math.ldexp(sgn * mant, 4 * (exp - 64) - 56)

        for index in 0...7 {
            //let mantaByte = bytes8_1st[index]
            //mantissa +=  Double(mantaByte) / pow(256.0, Double(index))
            let bit = pow(2.0, Double(7-index))
            let scaleBit = pow(2.0, Double( index ))
            var mantab = (8.0 * Double( bytes8_1st[1] & UInt8(bit)))/(bit*scaleBit)
            mantissa = mantissa + mantab
            mantab = (8.0 * Double( bytes8_1st[2] & UInt8(bit)))/(256.0 * bit * scaleBit)
            mantissa = mantissa + mantab
            mantab = (8.0 * Double( bytes8_1st[3] & UInt8(bit)))/(256.0 * bit * scaleBit)
            mantissa = mantissa + mantab

        }
        let real = mantissa * pow(16.0, Double(exponent))
```

UPDATE:

The following part seems to work for the exponent. Returns -9 for the data set I'm working with. Which is what I expect.

```
        var exp = Int16((bytes8 >> 56) & 0x7f)
        exp = exp - 65 //change from excess 64
        print(exp)

        var sgnVal = 0x8000000000000000 & bytes8
        var sgn = 1.0
        if(sgnVal == 1){
            sgn = -1.0
        }
```

For the mantissa though I can't get the calculation correct some how.

The data set:
3d 68 db 8b ac 71 0c b4
38 6d f3 7f 67 5e f6 ec

I think it should return 1e-9 for exponent and 0.0001

The closest I've gotten real    Double  0.0000000000034907316148746757

```
     var bytes7 = Array<UInt8>()
        for (index, by) in data.enumerated(){
            if(index < 4) {
             bytes7.append(by[0])
             bytes7.append(by[1])
            }
        }
        for index in 0...7 {
            mantissa += Double(bytes7[index]) / (pow(256.0, Double(index) + 1.0 ))
        }
        var real =  mantissa * pow(16.0, Double(exp));
        print(mantissa)
```

END OF UPDATE.

Also doesn't seem to produce the correct values. This one was based on a C file.

If anyone can help me out with an English explanation of what the spec means, or any pointers on what to do I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the doc, this code returns the 8-byte *Real* data as `Double`.

```
extension Data {
    func readUInt64BE(_ offset: Int) -> UInt64 {
        var value: UInt64 = 0
        _ = Swift.withUnsafeMutableBytes(of: &value) {bytes in
            copyBytes(to: bytes, from: offset..<offset+8)
        }
        return value.bigEndian
    }
    func readReal64(_ offset: Int) -> Double {
        let bitPattern = readUInt64BE(offset)
        let sign: FloatingPointSign = (bitPattern & 0x80000000_00000000) != 0 ? .minus: .plus
        let exponent = (Int((bitPattern >> 56) & 0x00000000_0000007F)-64) * 4 - 56
        let significand = Double(bitPattern & 0x00FFFFFF_FFFFFFFF)
        let result = Double(sign: sign, exponent: exponent, significand: significand)
        return result
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
//Two 8-byte Real data taken from the example in the doc
let data = Data([
    //1.0000000000000E-03
    0x3e, 0x41, 0x89, 0x37, 0x4b, 0xc6, 0xa7, 0xef,
    //1.0000000000000E-09
    0x39, 0x44, 0xb8, 0x2f, 0xa0, 0x9b, 0x5a, 0x54,
])
let real1 = data.readReal64(0)
let real2 = data.readReal64(8)
print(real1, real2) //->0.001 1e-09
```

Another example from "UPDATE":

```
//0.0001 in "UPDATE"
let data = Data([0x3d, 0x68, 0xdb, 0x8b, 0xac, 0x71, 0x0c, 0xb4, 0x38, 0x6d, 0xf3, 0x7f, 0x67, 0x5e, 0xf6, 0xec])
let real = data.readReal64(0)
print(real) //->0.0001
```

Please remember that `Double` has only 52-bit significand (mantissa), so this code loses some significant bits in the original 8-byte *Real*. I'm not sure that can be an issue or not.